# How to put limitation on url patterns in Django 2

Tags: python, regex, url-routing, django-2.0

Django 1.11 uses regular expression to check for appropriate url. eg

`url(r'^(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.abc),`

Here I could check that my year is 4 digits.

The new way introduced is like

`path('<int:year>/', views.abc),`

Is there a default way to use restrictions using `path()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly lifted from the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters)

You can define your custom converters:

```
class FourDigitYearConverter:
    regex = '[0-9]{4}'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return int(value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return '%04d' % value
```

Then:

```
from django.urls import register_converter, path

from . import converters, views

register_converter(converters.FourDigitYearConverter, 'yyyy')

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
    path('articles/<yyyy:year>/', views.year_archive),
    ...
]
```